# How to redirect multiple links into div on website using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a landing page with lots of links to individual html files on my website domain. Is it possible to load these other html files within a div on my landing page?

Meaning, instead of:

```
Homepage.com
  Link 1 > takes you to new page homepage.com/link1.html
  Link 2 > takes you to this page homepage.com/link2.html
  Link 3 > takes you to this other page homepage.com/link3.html
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
Homepage.com
  [search box where autocompleted selection takes you to links]
  ------
  <div class='content'>
     html is loaded here
  </div>
```

I can use jqueryui to link autocomplete to the input field, but I can't figure out how to link the selected term to load a new page.

Thanks

Comment: If the other pages are full html pages (not just snippets) then you would be better off using an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** is probably what you are looking for. You can even specify a container element to pull from on that page.

```
$('.content').load('homepage.com/link1.html #container');
```